# Orbeon Form Builder to send all files on save

Tags: orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

We implemented a web service that gets called on save. Can we get Form Builder to send all files uploaded in the form every time the form is saved, instead of just the files that were newly uploaded since the last time the form was saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you're implementing the [persistence API](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/persistence-api). Assuming this is the case, the short answer is *no*.

But then, why would you want that to happen? If a file has already been saved to your persistence layer, when the data is saved you get the form definition with a "link" to that saved file. If you need to retrieve it, you can do so, but, unless I misunderstand what you're doing, you don't need to get it back from Form Builder.

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what I mean. I want it to easly get data + all uploadesd files conected to this form for example to download it. I have to read xml and get files using links.

Comment: OK, great, I'm glad this worked for you, and thanks for the update. (BTW, you can also accept the answer above, so other going through this see that this solved your problem.)